# mysqlworkbench tcp/ip over ssh issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am attempting to make a remote connection in mysqlworkbench over Standard TCP/IP over SSH.
But I am getting "Failed to connect...."
With the connections credentials I have, I am able to connect to a remote phpmyadmin server page. And i have no problems connecting to my local mysql through mysqlworkbench.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score -1):

PMA is not the same as remote access via SSH. You got a timeout error, so something is blocking your way (firewalls?).

Comment: Sorry, yeah it was the wrong image i had uploaded, I will check if its a firewall issue? 
Forgot to mention that I am on a Mac OS Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: The firewall was actually off, so it can't be that

Comment: Is the server running? Can you reach any other service via the tunnel (e.g. open a remote shell)?